# Why does ExtJS 4.2.2 filefield button text disappear on tab from text input?

Tags: extjs

When I press tab key to move from filefield text input to the button, the button text disappears. I tried settings tabIndex to -1 but does not prevent tab to the button. Any ideas?

[image]

```
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    height: 30,
    name: 'licensefile',
    allowBlank: false,
    flex: 1,
    buttonMargin: 10,
    buttonConfig: {
        width: 70,
        height: 30,
        padding: '5 0 0 0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Ext JS version is that?

Comment: We are using ExtJS 4.2.2

Comment: Can you reduce this to a test case in fiddle? Also you would be better off asking questions like that in Sencha forum, so that support personnel could open dev tickets.

Comment: Could not repro in fiddle, though I can try some more. Sencha forums are lame at best. StackOverflow rocks!

Comment: StackOverflow is a good place to share experience, but is not very good for technical support kind of questions. We never promised to provide support on SO, and nobody I know on the support team is monitoring SO. Hence, your chance of getting help with a bug depends on whether someone on the dev team has enough time to look through SO and find your question, which may take a long time if ever.